# Kind kubernetes cluster failed to pull docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I tried to use [KinD](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) as an alternative of Minikube to bootstrap a K8S cluster in my local machine.

The cluster is created successfully.

But when I tried to create some pods/deployments from images, it failed.

```sh
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
$ kubectl run hello --image=hello-world
```

After some minutes, use `get pods` to get a failed status.

```sh
$ kubectl get pods
NAME    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          11m
nginx   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          22m
```

I am afraid this is another Global Firewall problem in China.

```sh
kubectl describe pods/nginx
Name:         nginx
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         dev-control-plane/172.19.0.2
Start Time:   Sun, 30 Aug 2020 19:46:06 +0800
Labels:       run=nginx
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.244.0.5
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.0.5
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImagePull
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mgq96 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-mgq96:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mgq96
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                        Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                        -------
  Normal   Scheduled  56m                default-scheduler           Successfully assigned default/nginx to dev-control-plane
  Normal   BackOff    40m                kubelet, dev-control-plane  Back-off pulling image "nginx"
  Warning  Failed     40m                kubelet, dev-control-plane  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Warning  Failed     13m (x3 over 40m)  kubelet, dev-control-plane  Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to copy: unexpected EOF
  Warning  Failed     13m (x3 over 40m)  kubelet, dev-control-plane  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   Pulling    13m (x4 over 56m)  kubelet, dev-control-plane  Pulling image "nginx"
```

When I entered to the kindest/node container, but there is no docker in it. **Not sure how KIND works**, originally I understand it deploys a K8S cluster into a Docker container.

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
a644f8b61314        kindest/node:v1.19.0   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    127.0.0.1:52301->6443/tcp   dev-control-plane

$ docker exec -it  a644f8b61314  /bin/bash
root@dev-control-plane:/# docker -v
bash: docker: command not found
```

After reading the Kind docs, I can not find an option to set a repository mirror there like that in Minikube.

BTW, I am using the latest Docker Desktop beta on a Windows 10.

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl describe pod nginx`?

Comment: @DavidLosert Appended it in the post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First pull the image in your local system using `docker pull nginx` and then use below command to load that image to the kind cluster

```
kind load docker-image nginx --name kind-cluster-name
```

Kind uses [containerd](https://github.com/containerd) instead of docker as runtime, that's why docker is not installed on the nodes.

Alternatively you can use [crictl](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/crictl.md) tool to pull and check images inside the kind node.

```
crictl pull nginx
crictl images
```

Comment: This works, if possible to use the Docker registry mirror for containerd. Not sure why containerd pull images from Docker hub failed

Answer (score 1):

I've run into same issue because I've exported `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` before creating cluster to a local proxy (127.0.0.1), which is unrechable in the cluster. After unset http(s)_proxy and recreate cluster, everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers did not help in my case: there is the need to set the `http(s)_proxy` environment variables before you run `kind create cluster`. Only setting the environment for docker resp. containerd does not help here:

```
export http_proxy=http://...
export https_proxy=http://...

kind create cluster --config ...
```